# Doctrine 2 - MySQL data type Double in YAML

Tags: php, double, yaml, doctrine-orm

I'm using codeigniter with Doctrine 2 with CodeIgniter2.
I used YAML Schema files to define database schema.
I want to define two columns in my table with MySQL data-type Double.
Below is the YAML Mapping I tried

```
Entities\Location:
  type: entity
  table: locations
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    Name:
      type: string
      length: 40
      nullable: false
    longitude:
      type: double
    latitude:
      type: double
```

But the code throws error when I try to create Models from YAML.

Entities were created successfully.

The Error Messages are:

> **Class double does not exist** while trying to create proxies

and

> **Unknown column type double requested** while trying to create schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.2 I think it was 'float' or 'decimal'.  Try one of those.

Here's a reference to the 1.2 docs... I'm struggling to find the 2.x docs that say the same thing.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/pl

Comment: Thanks. I was able to create the schema successfully with type as **float** in YAML.
And the database table field generated was double just as I wanted :-)

Comment: Ah good, I'm glad.  I find it very strange how the none of the examples appear to use float types. :)

Comment: Just for reference, the documentation on the types for doctrine 2 are to be found here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types